# JavaScript strings not being evaluated correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery and the jQuery URL plugin.

I have the following code:

```
$('#secondary-nav > li > ul > li > a').each( function() {
    var aHref = new String( $(this).attr('href') );
    alert (aHref);
    var wUrl = new String( $.url().attr('file') );
    alert (wUrl);
    alert ( aHref === wUrl );
});
```

Both aHref and wUrl are string objects (which I have confirmed by using instanceof). But the comparison comes back as false. The code is on "pageA.html" and one of the anchor's href is "pageA.html", but it never evaluates to true.

Comment: Just out of interest, do they compare correctly if you use == instead of === ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript distinguishes, confusingly, between string *values* and String *objects*. Even more confusingly, they are interchangeable in many contexts; `===` is one of the few cases where it actually makes a difference. For *objects*, `===` tests if the two sides are *the same* object, created by one particular constructor call. String *values*, on the other hand, compare by content.

With your `new String(...)` you explicitly ask to get actual String *objects* from the values you feed into the constructor. This means that you get the strict sense of `===` when you later compare them.

To fix your problem, simply omit the `new String` from the code.

Comment: +1 to demonstrate, try `"foo" === new String("foo")`, the result should be `false` (confusingly).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I figured out it was just a stupid typo on my part.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to create a new String object, you could simply replace them with `var aHref = $(this).attr('href');`. You cant as easily compare object as you can compare simple strings. If you don't create new Objects, `aHref === wUrl` would evaluate to `true`.

WHen comparing objects, they are usually converted to the same type, which in most cases is string (comparing string and int etc), but if they are both the same type (`String` in your case), they are not compared as simple string, but objects, in which case they are different objects. This is because variables that refer to objects, refer to the specific object instance (kind of like pointers in other languages). Since you are dealing with two distinct objects (they might have the same constuctor arguments, but are still located separately in memory), the `===` and also `==` will both evaluate to `false`. Also `aHref.toString() === wUrl.toString()`, would be evaluated to `true`, since they are first converted into simple strings, in which case they don't represent the object, but its stringified representation.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing two objects, javascript will look to see if *they are actually the same object*, not if they look the same. Thus `{foo:'bar'} == {foo:'bar'}` will evaluate to `false`.

If you want to compare strings by value, you'll have to use the string primitives: `var aHref = $(this).attr('href')` & `var wUrl = $.url().attr('file')`.

---

If, for some odd reason, you insist on creating your strings with the String constructor, you can coerce them into primitives:

```
alert ( aHref.toString() === wUrl.toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `alert ( aHref == wUrl );` which doesn't compare `TYPE`. or you can force strings:

```
( aHref+'' === wUrl+'' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what aHref and wUrl are in an example?

=== will return true if the strings are strictly equal (i.e same number of chars in the same order)